# Why Isn't smp.solve Solving This System?

Tags: python, sympy

Here is my code

```
import sympy as smp

i1, i2 = smp.symbols('i1 i2', Real=True)

eq1 = -40 + 2500*i2 - 2000*i1

eq2 = 8000*i1 - 2000*i2

i1_solved, i2_solved = smp.solve([eq1, eq2], [i1, i2])
```

I tried adding a [0] at the end of the smp.solve function but I get an error that states:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 3):

`solve()` returns a dict. You can access it's elements e.g. with `answer.get(i1)` or `answer[i1]` (thanks to @hpaulj).

```
import sympy as smp

i1, i2 = smp.symbols('i1 i2', Real=True)

eq1 = -40 + 2500*i2 - 2000*i1
eq2 = 8000*i1 - 2000*i2

answer = smp.solve([eq1, eq2], [i1, i2])

print(answer)
```

**Output:**

```
{i1: 1/200, i2: 1/50}
```

Comment: or `answer[i1]`

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks. It's now part of the answer.